# How do you apply an item, from a list of results, to the parent Div tag for the current object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to build a function for inserting the number of Facebook Likes into a Div tag. So far, I have a script that can get the URL from a Div tag which is inside of another Div tag called 'entry' and then have the .getJSON() method retrieve the number of Facebook likes for each entry.However, I can't get each retrieved value of Facebook Likes to insert into a Div tag for each entry. Please note, I simplified my code to where it alerts each Facebook Like value. This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="fburl">https://graph.facebook.com/zombies</div>
  <div class="facebook-likes"></div>
</div> 
<div class="entry">
  <div class="fburl">https://graph.facebook.com/starwars</div>
  <div class="facebook-likes"></div>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".entry").each(function() {
    var fbURL = $(this).find(".fburl").html();
    $.getJSON(fbURL, function(fbData) {
        var fbArr = fbData['likes'];
        alert(fbArr);
    });
});
});
```

​So what I am trying to do is iterate through each entry, get the Open Graph URL for it, retrieve the Likes value, and then insert it into the appropriate Div tag, so the code should render as:

```
<div class="entry">
 <div class="fburl">https://graph.facebook.com/zombies</div>
 <div class="facebook-likes">2,586 Likes</div>
</div> 
 <div class="entry">
  <div class="fburl">https://graph.facebook.com/starwars</div>
  <div class="facebook-likes">8,905,721 Likes</div>
</div>
```

​
​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.entry').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            fbURL = $this.children('.fburl').html();
        $.getJSON(fbURL, function(fbData) {
            $this.children('.facebook-likes').html(fbData['likes'] + ' Likes')
        });
    });
});
```

**See:** http://api.jquery.com/children

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/9EALz/2/

**Note:** Using `children()` is going to be marginally more efficient than using `find()` as it limits the DOM traversal to a single level ( http://jsperf.com/find-vs-children/13 ).  Cashing the jQuery object `$(this)` via `var $this = $(this)` is also slightly more efficient as it prevents unnecessary selector interpretation ( http://jsperf.com/jquery-cache-vs-no-chace ).

Comment: Thank you and I didn't know about caching $(this) that way. I like this code since it is simple. I'm not sure why I couldn't come up with this myself, it seems like I tried that combonation already but it could be because of how I was using .find() and because I was using fbData.likes earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You may want this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".entry").each(function() {
        var entry=$(this), fbURL=$(".fburl", entry).html(),
        el=$('.facebook-likes', entry);
        $.getJSON(fbURL, function(fbData) {
           el.html(numberWithCommas(fbData['likes'])+" Likes");
        });
    });
});​
```

A thousand separator function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ABEFV/8/).

### Update:

Alternatively you can use [**this too**](http://jsfiddle.net/ABEFV/7/) (using data-attribute) without an extra div for `fburl`, i.e.

```
<div class="entry">
    <div data-fburl="https://graph.facebook.com/zombies" class="facebook-likes"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".entry").each(function() {
    var entry=$(this), fbURL = $(".facebook-likes", entry).attr('data-fburl'),
    el=$('.facebook-likes', entry);
    $.getJSON(fbURL, function(fbData) {
        el.html(numberWithCommas(fbData['likes'])+" Likes");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the use of data-fburl so I will incorporate it into what coderabbi has written.